Error 500 when deployed on Vercel but working in local node.js
Cannot find module '@mongodb-js/saslprep'
Require stack:

/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client_auth_providers.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
/var/task/server/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
/var/task/server/index.js
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in package.json?
Node.js process exited with exit status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 870.99 ms    Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError

//here my package.json 




{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "npm install",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mongodb-js/saslprep": "^1.1.9",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.10",
    "express": "^4.19.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongodb": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.6.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.15",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "run": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.25.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4"
  }
}





//and this is my vercel.json 


{
    "version":2,
    "builds": [
      {
          "src": "./index.js",
          "use": "@vercel/node" 
      }
    
    ],

    "routes": [
         {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/",

            "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"]
         }
     ]
  }






//and this is my index file 



const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserRoutes = require("./routes/User");
const morgan = require("morgan");
require('dotenv').config();

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
// CORS configuration
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://fitness-track-frontend-using-mern.vercel.app", // Frontend URL for production
  methods: ['GET','POST','PUT',"DELETE"],
  credentials: true, // Allow cookies
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for form data
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

app.use("/api/user/", UserRoutes);
app.use(express.static('Public'))

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const status = err.status || 500;
  const message = err.message || "Something went wrong";
  return res.status(status).json({
    success: false,
    status,
    message,
  });
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Hello developers",
  })
}); 

var mongoURL = 'mongodb+srv://dinukgunasekara286:Bzt3SrJYtm5htN4H@fitnessdb.w1xusgy.mongodb.net/'

const connectDB = () => {
  mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);
  mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL|| mongoURL)
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to Mongo DB"))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("failed to connect with mongo");
      console.error(err);
    });
};

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    connectDB();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8005; // Dynamic port
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));  
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    }
};

startServer();

module.exports = app; 



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
